# javascript - IF ELSE operators

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operators

Learning the basics and had this exercise:

"Write a function addWithSurcharge that adds two amounts with surcharge. For each amount less than or equal to 10, the surcharge is 1. For each amount greater than 10, the surcharge is 2. The call addWithSurcharge(5, 15) should return 23."

I had put:

```
function addWithSurcharge(num1, num2) {
if (num1 <= 10) {
num1 += 1;
} else {
num1 += 2;
}
if (num2 <= 10) {
num2 += 1;
} else {
num2 += 2;
}
return num1 + num2;
}
```

Which works, but want to learn better syntax. Could something like

```
if (num1, num2 <= 10) {...
```

work? I realize can't do the || operator because it could affect the wrong num.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this would be to use the ternary opertator

```js
function addWithSurcharge(num1,num2)
{        
    num1 += num1 <= 10 ? 1 : 2;
    num2 += num2 <= 10 ? 1 : 2;
    return num1 + num2;
}

console.log(addWithSurcharge(10,5));
```

If you use a ? when assigning a value it'll evaluate whatever is on the left hand side of the ? and either return the left hand side of the : if it's true or the right hand side if it's false.

Answer (score 2):

Put the numbers into an array instead, and iterate over the array so you don't have to repeat both the `num1` and `num2`:

```js
function addWithSurcharge(...nums) {
  return nums.reduce((a, num) => {
    if (num <= 10) {
      num += 1;
    } else {
      num += 2;
    }
    return a + num;
  }, 0);
}
console.log(addWithSurcharge(5, 15));
```

Without `.reduce`, the above is equivalent to:

```js
function addWithSurcharge(...nums) {
  nums.forEach((num, i) => {
    if (num <= 10) {
      nums[i] += 1;
    } else {
      nums[i] += 2;
    }
  });
  return nums[0] + nums[1];
}
console.log(addWithSurcharge(5, 15));
```

You can use the conditional operator to make the `if`/`else` part more concise without bothering with reassignment, too:

```js
const addWithSurcharge = (...nums) => (
  nums.reduce(
    (a, num) => a + num + (num <= 10 ? 1 : 2),
    0
  )
);
console.log(addWithSurcharge(5, 15));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
function addWithSurcharge(num1, num2) {
return num1 + num2 + num1<=10?1:2 + num2<=10?1:2;
}
```

The `num1<=10?1:2` basically means `if(num1<=10){1} else{2}` which works really well!

Comment: This is pretty clever! Thanks for teaching me this ? operator.

Comment: Yeah sure! The basic format is like this: `bool?val1:val2`

If the bool is true then it will return `val1`
Otherwise it will return `val2`.

So we can use this as an inline if(){}else(){} statement.

How that works is `num1<=10` is the boolean and `1` and `2` are the nums

Answer (score 2):

The most basic improvement is a helper function that you can call twice:

```
function withSurcharge(num) {
  if (num <= 10) return num + 1;
  else return num + 2;
}
function addWithSurcharge(num1, num2) {
  return withSurcharge(num1) + withSurcharge(num2);
}
```

You could further shorten the `if`/`else` statement to use a conditional expression, but not much is gained by that:

```
return num + (num <= 10 ? 1 : 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still struggling with syntax. From the examples I'm playing with and seeing I didn't know you could put a functions parameter as another functions parameter--I probably said that wrong.